# Java naming conventions: Interface vs concrete method name

Tags: java, coding-style

Interfaces are used to represent same behaviour in multiple classes.

You are writing Spring components, which will do 90% the same stuff. This means, you will have a method e.g. to create, delete or get something back.
While these methods will do similar tasks and behave the same way (error handling while validation etc.), the business logic is not common, so you can't put the all together.
Regarding to my example, is it better to implement only Interface methods

```
public void add(Object t);
public void remove(Object t);
```

or is it better to give the methods real names

```
public void addPerson(Object t);
public void addCar(Object t);
public void removePerson(Object t);
public void removeCar(Object t);
```

Another option would be to pack all add or remove methods inside the addPerson or removePerson methods.

Comment: regardless, it is better to avoid having an `Object` as parameter, but give a more specific type. (Like a Car or a Person in your case). You may want to look into generics, too

Comment: My code should only illustrate what I want :)

Comment: typically, you could have an interface that says `interface Component<T> { void add(T t); }` and an implementation `class Concrete implements Component<Car> { public void add(Car car) {} }`

Comment: I would look at how the code is used and whether you get more readability out of one way or the other. For example naming repository methods: Specific names allow `repo.findUser(id)` generic ones work better with `userRepository.find(id)`. But you can still do it "wrong" and get confused by `repo.find(id)` or annoyed by  `userRepository.findUser(id)`.